# Node Convert String to HTTP Header

Tags: node.js

I have ByteBuffer which I have converted to a String.  Is there a nice way to convert that to an "object" like [http.IncomingMessage](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) so that I can do something like this:

```
var message = stringToIncomingMessage(buf.toString());
var host = message.headers['host']
```

I essentially need a nice way of extracting the Host field from the string version of an HTTP request.  I tried using a regex to find "Host", but sanitizing got complicated.

Comment: Not really.  The implementation is a bit messy:  https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_incoming.js#L40  There are other HTTP parsers for JS though.  Perhaps one of them might be more helpful.